# Writing a JIT compiler in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, code-generation, jit, self-modifying

I've written a virtual machine in C which has decent performance for a non-JIT VM, but I want to learn something new, and improve performance. My current implementation simply uses a switch to translate from VM bytecode to instructions, which is compiled to a jump table. Like I said, decent performance for what it is, but I've hit a barrier that can only be overcome with a JIT compiler.

I've already asked a similar question not long ago about self-modifying code, but I came to realize that I wasn't asking the right question.

So my goal is to write a JIT compiler for this C virtual machine, and I want to do it in x86 assembly. (I'm using NASM as my assembler) I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this. I'm comfortable with assembly, and I've looked over some self-modifying code examples, but I haven't come to figure out how to do code generation just yet.

My main block so far is copying instructions to an executable piece of memory, *with* my arguments. I'm aware that I can label a certain line in NASM, and copy the entire line from that address with the static arguments, but that's not very dynamic, and doesn't work for a JIT compiler. I need to be able to interpret the instruction from bytecode, copy it to executable memory, interpret the first argument, copy it to memory, then interpret the second argument, and copy it to memory.

I've been informed about several libraries that would make this task easier, such as GNU lightning, and even LLVM. However, I'd like to write this by hand first, to understand how it works, before using external resources.

Are there any resources or examples this community could provide to help me get started on this task? A simple example showing two or three instructions like "add" and "mov" being used to generate executable code, with arguments, dynamically, in memory, would do wonders.

Comment: Just because a jitter generates machine code does *not* mean that it itself needs to be written in assembly.  It makes no sense to do so.

Comment: An intermediate step to try is threaded dispatch using GCC's computed goto extension (using `void *optable[] = { &&op_add, &&op_subtract, ... }` and each operand is `op_add: ... goto *optable[*ip++];`).  I've seen big gains in switched interpreters like you describe.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend writing a JIT in assembly at all.  There are good arguments for writing the most frequently executed bits of the *interpreter* in assembly.  For an example of how this looks like see this [comment from Mike Pall](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/badl2/luajit_2_beta_3_is_out_support_both_x32_x64/c0lrus0), the author of LuaJIT.

As for the JIT, there are many different levels with varying complexity:

1. Compile a basic block (a sequence of non-branching instructions) by simply copying the interpreter's code.  For example, the implementations of a few (register-based) bytecode instructions might look like this:

   ```
   ; ebp points to virtual register 0 on the stack
   instr_ADD:
       <decode instruction>
       mov eax, [ebp + ecx * 4]  ; load first operand from stack
       add eax, [ebp + edx * 4]  ; add second operand from stack
       mov [ebp + ebx * 4], eax  ; write back result
       <dispatch next instruction>
   instr_SUB:
       ... ; similar
   ```

   So, given the instruction sequence `ADD R3, R1, R2`, `SUB R3, R3, R4` a simple JIT could copy the relevant parts of the interpreters implementation into a new machine code chunk:

   ```
       mov ecx, 1
       mov edx, 2
       mov ebx, 3
       mov eax, [ebp + ecx * 4]  ; load first operand from stack
       add eax, [ebp + edx * 4]  ; add second operand from stack
       mov [ebp + ebx * 4], eax  ; write back result
       mov ecx, 3
       mov edx, 4
       mov ebx, 3
       mov eax, [ebp + ecx * 4]  ; load first operand from stack
       sub eax, [ebp + edx * 4]  ; add second operand from stack
       mov [ebp + ebx * 4], eax  ; write back result
   ```

   This simply copies the relevant code, so we need to initialise the registers used accordingly.  A better solution would be to translate this directly into machine instructions `mov eax, [ebp + 4]`, but now you already have to manually encode the requested instructions.

   This technique removes the overheads of interpretation, but otherwise does not improve efficiency much.  If the code is executed for only one or two times, then it may not worth it to first translate it to machine code (which requires flushing at least parts of the I-cache).
2. While some JITs use the above technique instead of an interpreter, they then employ a more complicated optimisation mechanism for frequently executed code.  This involves translating the executed bytecode into an intermediate representation (IR) on which additional optimisations are performed.

   Depending on the source language and the type of JIT, this can be very complex (which is why many JITs delegate this task to LLVM).  A method-based JIT needs to deal with joining control-flow graphs, so they use SSA form and run various analyses on that (e.g., Hotspot).

   A tracing JIT (like LuaJIT 2) only compiles straight line code which makes many things easier to implement, but you have to be very careful how you pick traces and how you link multiple traces together efficiently.  Gal and Franz describe one method in [this paper (PDF)](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~franz/Site/pubs-pdf/ICS-TR-06-16.pdf).      For another method see the LuaJIT source code.  Both JITs are written in C (or perhaps C++).

Comment: Right, at the end of each basic block you must fall back to a routine that decides where to branch.  This then results in a new bytecode address which must be mapped to an address of the corresponding machine code.  There is a technique called [context threading (PDF)](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/syslab/pubs/zaleski_shapes2005.pdf) that allows for more smoother integration of interpreter and JIT.  The main idea is to translate branches into actual machine instructions so the branch predictor can see them.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you look at the project http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/. By using the framework it provides, you can save a lot of energy. If you want write all things by hand, just read the source and rewrite it yourself, I think it's not very hard.